# Pass down onChange to child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

I have a react component and I want to pass down onChange as a prop to a child component, I'm using atomic design, here's my code:

**HeadComponent.js**

```
class Headcomponent extends React.Component{

  constructor (props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      formErrors: {email: '', password: ''},
      emailValid: false,
      passwordValid: false,
      formValid: false,
      items: [],

    }
  }

  handleUserInput = (e) => {

    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({[name]: value},
                  () => { this.validateField(name, value) });
  }

render(){

    const fields= [
    {
      label: 'hhdghghd',
      placeholder: 'fhfhhfhh 1',
      ExampleMessage: this.state.formErrors.email ,
      ErrorMessage: 'error message for input 1',
      inputValue: this.state.email,
      onChange: this.handleUserInput  //this is where I'm passing my function


    },
    {
      label: 'fffff',
      placeholder: 'tttttt 2',
      ExampleMessage: 'example message  for second label',
      ErrorMessage: 'error message for input 2',
      onChange: this.handleUserInput


    },
  ]

return (
    <div>

  <Form fields={fields} buttonText="Submit"/>

    </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Headcomponent;
```

**Form.js**

```
    const Form = props => (
      <form className="Form">
        {
          props.fields.map((field, i) => (<LabeledInput label={field.label}
           placeholder={field.placeholder}
           ExampleMessage={field.ExampleMessage}
           ErrorMessage={field.ErrorMessage}
           onChange= {(e)=> field.onChange}
           inputValue= {field.inputValue}
           key={i}
           passwordError={props.passwordError}

           />))
        }
        <Button text={props.buttonText} />
      </form>
    );

    Form.propTypes = {
      fields: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
      buttonText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    };

    export default Form;
```

**LabeledInput**

```
const LabeledInput = props => (
  <div className={`form-group `} >
    <Label text={props.label} />
    <Input inputValue={props.inputValue} placeholder={props.placeholder} type="text" onChange={(e)=> props.onChange} />

    <ErrorMessage text={props.ErrorMessage} />
    <ExampleMessage ExampleMessage={ props.ExampleMessage} />
  </div>
);

LabeledInput.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  //value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  exampleText: PropTypes.string,
};
export default LabeledInput;
```

**Input.js**

```
const Input = props => (
  <input type={props.type} class="form-control form-control-success is-valid" placeholder={props.placeholder} value={props.inputValue} className="form-control form-control-success"
      onChange={ (e)=> props.onChange } />
);

Input.propTypes = {

  inputValue: PropTypes.string,
  type: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default Input;
```

How to pass `handleUserInput` from `HeadComponent.js` down to `Input.js`, so far using props I can't get it to trigger while changing text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to actually call `field.onChange` method. Instead of :

```
onChange= {(e)=> field.onChange}
```

You can change it to:

```
onChange= {field.onChange}
```

I also noticed that your `handleUserInput` set state at :

```
{ [name]: e.target.value }
```

However, you are not setting `name` to any of the inputs and that's not gonna work.

Please have a look at my working sample:

```js
const LabeledInput = props => (
  <div className="form-group">
    <label>{props.label}</label>
    <input
      className="form-control"
      type="text"
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      onChange={props.onChange} // That's how you have to call onChange
      name={props.name} // You are not setting this prop
    />
    <div>{props.ErrorMessage}</div>
    <div>{props.ExampleMessage}</div>
  </div>
)

const Form = ({ buttonText, fields }) => (
  <form className="Form">
    {fields.map((field, i) => <LabeledInput key={i} {...field} />)}
    <button className="btn btn-primary">{buttonText}</button>
  </form>
)

class Headcomponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      formErrors: {email: '', password: ''},
      emailValid: false,
      passwordValid: false,
      formValid: false,
      items: [],
    }

    this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this)
  }
  
  handleUserInput(e) {
    const name = e.target.name
    const value = e.target.value
    // Now that you have `name` and `value`, state updates are going to work
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  }

  render() {
    const fields = [
      {
        label: 'Email',
        placeholder: 'email placeholder',
        ExampleMessage: this.state.formErrors.email ,
        ErrorMessage: 'error message for input 1',
        inputValue: this.state.email,
        onChange: this.handleUserInput,
        name: 'email',
      },
      {
        label: 'Password',
        placeholder: 'password placeholder',
        ExampleMessage: 'example message  for second label',
        ErrorMessage: 'error message for input 2',
        onChange: this.handleUserInput,
        name: 'password',
      },
    ]
    
    return (
      <div>
        <Form fields={fields} buttonText="Submit"/>
        
        <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <div>state.email: {this.state.email}</div>
          <div>state.password: {this.state.password}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Headcomponent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I'd vote for the 2rd option, because with the first option you end up creating new functions on every render. Plus he has the same issue on Input.js and Form.js. :)

Comment: Still the same behaviour, also I don't know if you noticed but I'm passing the function down multiple levels, the idea is that Input.js is the component that should finally fire the function.

Comment: Yes, change this: onChange={ (e)=> props.onChange }  to -> onChange={props.onChange} too

Comment: @GherbiHicham have you changed the way you trigger `onChange` in `Input` component as well?

Comment: Yes I applied it to all child components and still nothing

Comment: ok so in Form.js you have to change: onChange= {(e)=> field.onChange} to onChange={field.onChange}, then on LabeledInput.js change onChange={(e)=> props.onChange} to onChange={props.onChange} and Input.js change onChange={ (e)=> props.onChange }  to onChange={props.onChange}

Comment: I agree with @ArberSylejmani. You need to change all occurrences when you use `onChange` in order to make it work

Comment: @ArberSylejmani I actually tried the first time and it didn't work, still doesn't work now, am I doing something else entirely wrong?

Comment: Do you see any errors? Also this doesn't belong in JSX: class="form-control form-control-success is-valid" you have class and className, remove the class one

Comment: @GherbiHicham I've found some errors in your code and updated my answer. Please let me know whether it works now :)

Comment: Ok, I will try this, but do I have to pass name all the way down as well?

Comment: @GherbiHicham yes, since you are using `event.target.name` in `handleUserInput`